# Populate table with jquery and ajax through json passed through controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio

Trying to create a table with the use of jquery and ajax but I am having issues with setting it up so that it appears like the output below. The main issue I seem to be having is getting the return from my controller to pass into my view where the table should be created. Im not quite sure how to pass through the data through the controller to the view page and then manipulate it to form a table. My json is as follows:
`[
  {
    "category": 1,
    "speedCategory": "0-3km/h",
    "year": 2015,
    "count": 17008
  },
  {
    "category": 2,
    "speedCategory": "3-6km/h",
    "year": 2015,
    "count": 4,694
  },
  {
    "category": 1,
    "speedCategory": "0-3km/h",
    "year": 2016,
    "count": 12546
  },
  {
    "category": 2,
    "speedCategory": "3-6km/h",
    "year": 2016,
    "count": 500
  }`
Etc.

And here is the controller that I am using to try and return the information:
`

```
public class SpeedWebAPIController : ApiController
{
    private SpeedEntities db = new SpeedEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public object GetSpeedWebAPI()
    {
        var speedCodes = (
            from ec in db.speedCodes
            join e in db.Speed
            on ec.speedTimeCode equals e.speedTimeCode
            select new
            {
                ec.category,
                ec.speedCategory,
                e.year
            })
               .GroupBy(p => new
               {
                   p.category,
                   p.speedCategory,
                   year = p.Year
               })
               .Select(p => new
               {
                   p.Key.category,
                   p.Key.speedCategory,
                   p.Key.year,
                   Count = p.Count()
               })
               .OrderBy(p => p.year)
               .ThenBy(p => p.category)
            .ToList();
        return speedCodes;
    }`
```

And I'm trying to get it to append into my table here with the use of jquery at the bottom of the page:
`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4" id="table">
</div>
<script>
//Not sure how to pass in controller return and then create a jquery table 
//with this
</script>`
```

The table output should appear as such:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|    Speed     |    Count    |
+--------------+-------------+
|             2015           |
+--------------+-------------+
| 0 to 3km/h   |    17,008   |
+--------------+-------------+
| 3km/h to 6km |    4,694    |
+--------------+-------------+
| 6km/h to 10km|    4,895    |
+--------------+-------------+
|             2016           |
+--------------+-------------+
| 0 to 3km/h   |    12,546   |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Etc..
So it has overall table headings of Speed and Count and then subheadings of years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datatables to accomplish your task.

This is called [RowGrouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html) and I had made a sample for you [here](http://live.datatables.net/taduvomu/1/edit).

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>SpeedCategory</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>SpeedCategory</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2015</td>
            <td>0-3kmph</td>
            <td>17008</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2015</td>
            <td>3-6kmph</td>
            <td>4,694</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>0-3kmph</td>
            <td>12546</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2016</td>
            <td>3-6kmph</td>
            <td>500</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
      var groupColumn = 1;
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": groupColumn }
        ],
        "order": [[ groupColumn, 'asc' ]],
        "displayLength": 25,
        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;

            api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append your returned json data using jquery in your table tbody dynamically.

```js
var jsonData= $.parseJSON('{"response":[["3km/h","17,008"],["2km/h","200"]]}');
$.each(jsonData, function(i, d) {
   var row='<tr>';
   $.each(d, function(j, e) {
      row+='<td>'+e+'</td>';
   });
   row+='</tr>';
   $('#myTable tbody').append(row);
});
```

```html
 <table class="table" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Speed</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>           
        </thead>           
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: With the first line (var jsonData= $.parseJSON line) you hard code in the data. How could I instead call a function from a controller and return the data instead that way? Only reason is I have many entries. Secondly I still need to group it via years for a subheading. For example it should have the speeds and counts put under the years they where achieved in.

Comment: Write a $.ajax call and in success response function you'll have your data which is returned from controller.